# Dynamic Programming: Calculating kth parentheses sequence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, catalan

An n parentheses sequence consists of n "("s and n ")"s.

A valid parentheses sequence is defined as the following:

You can find a way to repeat erasing adjacent pair of parentheses "()" until it becomes empty.

For example, "(())" is a valid parentheses, you can erase the pair on the 2nd and 3rd position and it becomes "()", then you can make it empty.
")()(" is not a valid parentheses, after you erase the pair on the 2nd and 3rd position, it becomes ")(" and you cannot erase any more.

Now, we have all valid n parentheses sequences. Find the k-th smallest sequence in lexicographical order.

For example, here are all valid 3 parentheses sequences in lexicographical order:

```
((()))
(()())
(())()
()(())
()()()
```

Source :https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/4214486/dashboard#s=p3

Note: Contest in now over and solutions are available to download.

I have solved it for small input ( k < 10<sup>6</sup> ) by using next_permutation() which is available in C++ STL. I am unable to formulate a sub problem for this. I have a tried to solve this by using Catalan's number but didn't seem to get any success. I don't want to see the solutions as it doesn't help in learning. Kindly help me in identifying a sub problem.

Comment: Where is the first closing parenthesis ? You have `n/2` positions that can hold it. Thus, you have `u(n) = n/2 * u(n-2)`. You then remove the first "()" substring and get an `n-2` valid sequence. Where is the first closing parenthesis in this substring, you still have `(n-2)/2` choices ! And so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let *N* denote the *length* of the sequence (i.e. 2 *n*).

The key is to be able to *count* the number of valid sequences of length *N*.

If you have a function, *countValid*(*N*, *depth*) you can solve the original problem as follows:

1. If *depth* < 0 it's impossible (a negative depth means invalid sequence)
2. If *k* < *countValid*(*N*-1, *depth*+1) append `(` (because the sought sequence lies in the first half of the remaining search space)
3. Otherwise append `)` (because the sought sequence lies in the second half of the total search space)
4. Continue from 1 with updated *N*-1 and *depth*+1 if you chose `(` above, or *depth*-1 if you chose `)` above.

---

*countValid*(*N*, *depth*) can be implemented with dynamic programming with a standard DP matrix, *M*, with the two arguments as indexes:

- The base case, *M*[0,0] = 1 since there is *one* valid 0-length sequence (the empty sequence)
- For all other values in the first column *M*[0, 1...*N*] is 0.
- For *M*[*N*,*depth*] you just add up

  - the number of valid sequences after opening: *M*[*N*-1, *depth*-1], and
  - the number of valid sequences after closing: *M*[*N*-1, *depth*+1]

  that is: *M*[*N*,*depth*] = *M*[*N*-1, *depth*-1] + *M*[*N*-1, *depth*+1]

Comment: A valid sequence can only be of even length. So I'm guessing you mean a length of `2.n` instead of `n` ?

Comment: @Rerito You deleted your answer. Was their a problem in that approach?

Comment: @Rerito Yes n parentheses means sequence of length 2n

Comment: @HarshilLodhi, yes my recursion relation was clearly false ! The approach of aioobe is the one that you must study.

Comment: @aioobe I see, perhaps stating what _n_ and _depth_ represent would help us understand at first sight ! I think I got it :)

Comment: Updated answer. I can't rely on *n* in the solution, because odd length is important when there is an odd depth.

Comment: @aioobe Can you please add a line explaining the depth with an example??

Comment: The depth is the current nesting. (() has depth 1. See it as the numer of opening parens minus the number off closing parens if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but some people may come back to this. I had a hard time implementing aioobe's solution, as I think it misses a step:

3.1) If you chose ")", then k = k - countValid(N-1, depth+1)

Intuitively the reasoning goes like this. If you selected to decrease the depth, then the sequence you are looking for is in the second part of the search space that is divided at (N, depth). If we keep k the same, it will at some point along the path be bigger than all the remaining number of solutions and our traversal doesn't work anymore. We need to subtract the number of solutions we excluded along the way for the traversal of the matrix to produce the desired results.

Here is some java code for finding the k-th element if you have the matrix D containing the number of valid sequences for each (N,depth):

```
// get k-th element
int N = 2*n;
int d = 0;
String str = new String("");
while (N>0 && d >= 0) {
  // invalid elements (out of bounds or 0)
  if (d+1 > n || D[N-1][d+1] == 0) {
    str += ")"; d--;
  } else if (d-1 < 0 || D[N-1][d-1] == 0) {
    str += "("; d++;
  } else {
    if (k <= D[N-1][d+1]) {
      // first part of search-space
      str += "("; d++;
    } else {
      // second part of search-space
      str += ")";
      k -= D[N-1][d+1]; // substract number of excluded solutions
      d--;
    }
  }
  N--;
}

// For valid strings k should be 1
if (k != 1) str = "Doesn't Exist!";
```